# What is listener inside brackets and what does "inline" with "crossline" have to do with it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I found on [github](https://github.com/codinginflow/MVVMTodo/tree/Part-6_Room-Search) these lines of code and spend more than hour trying to understand.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_tasks, menu)

        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.onQueryTextChanged {
            viewModel.searchQuery.value = it
        }
    }
```

and this is the part im having hard time trying to understand:

```
inline fun SearchView.onQueryTextChanged(crossinline listener: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            listener(newText.orEmpty())
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

I literally don't understand almost a single word.
inline crossline aside, can you explain me how listener works there.

P.S Im noob in kotlin, my first language is Java

Comment: To take a guess at why you got down-voted: `inline` and `crossinline` are explained in the Kotlin language documentation. If you haven't read about them there, then this question is wasting people's time. And if you have read the documentation, it would be very helpful if you said what about it specifically you didn't understand. Otherwise your question is basically asking people to retype the documentation and put in many extra details randomly in the hopes of explaining whichever detail it was that you didn't get. But you didn't say whether you read the documentation at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am learning Kotlin myself and thought I can help with the code snippet above.

`SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` is an interface with onQueryTextChange and onQueryTextSubmit methods - reference - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

`SearchView.onQueryTextChanged` function looks like an extension function on SearchView, which accepts a lambda named listener.

The listener lambda itself is a function which takes a string as param and returns Unit ie returns nothing. That means the function will do some side-effect eg IO, update some state etc.

Since `onQueryTextChanged` is an extension function, you get the reference to the object on which this function will be called as `this` in the function body

`object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` part is basically an object implementing the SearchView.OnQueryTextListener interface with both the methods from the interface overridden.

The object in above step is passed as param to setOnQueryTextListener method.

At the caller site, i.e.

```
searchView.onQueryTextChanged {
            viewModel.searchQuery.value = it
        }
```

Please note the `it` value is implicit param to a lambda, you can rewrite it to make it more readable as well,

```
searchView.onQueryTextChanged { newSearchQuery ->
            viewModel.searchQuery.value = newSearchQuery
        }
```

the listener lambda here is a function which takes a string and sets the value to viewModel.searchQuery.value.

The inline keyword basically replaces function call with function body directly at compile time, kind of what inline variable refactoring that can be done, although the compiler does it at compile time - kind of an optimization.